# Is $M^TM=I$ not the same as $\mathbf{v}^TM^TM\mathbf{v}=\mathbf{v}^T\mathbf{v}$???

Tags: linear-algebra, matrices, mathematica

I define a function $f[\mathbf{v}]$ as follows:

$$
f[\mathbf{v}]=\mathbf{v}^T\mathbf{v}
$$

I am now interested in a group of linear transformation $M$ ($n\times n$ matrices) which leaves the function invariant:

$$
f[M\mathbf{v}]=f[\mathbf{v}]
$$

To 'solve' for the properties of $M$, I consider two equality:

$$
M^TM=I\tag{1}
$$

$$
\mathbf{v}^TM^TM\mathbf{v}=\mathbf{v}^T\mathbf{v}\tag{2}
$$

---

Working out the details, I get different results for $M$ depending I use (1) or (2).

We assume $\operatorname{Dim} {\mathbf{v}}=2$ and $\operatorname{Dim} {M}=2 \times 2$.

$$
\mathbf{v}=\pmatrix{x\\y}\\
M=\pmatrix{a&b\\c&d}
$$

---

For (1), I want to solve:

$$
\pmatrix{a&c\\b&d}\pmatrix{a&b\\c&d}=\pmatrix{1&0\\0&1}\tag{1a}
$$

and for (2), I want to solve:

$$
\pmatrix{x&y}\pmatrix{a&c\\b&d}\pmatrix{a&b\\c&d}\pmatrix{x\\y} =x^2+y^2\tag{2a}
$$

---

Now, for (1) I get

$$
\left(
\begin{array}{cc}
 a^2+c^2 & a b+c d \\
 a b+c d & b^2+d^2 \\
\end{array}
\right)=\left(
\begin{array}{cc}
 1 & 0 \\
 0 & 1 \\
\end{array}
\right)\tag{1b}
$$

and for (2) I get

$$ 
(a x+b y)^2+(c x+d y)^2=x^2+y^2 \tag{2b}
$$

---

For (1) I clearly get the orthogonal group $O^TO=I$.

But for (2), using Mathematica:

```
Solve[(a x+b y)^2+(c x+d y)^2==x^2+y^2]
```

I get:

$$
\left\{\left\{d\to \frac{-\sqrt{-a^2 x^2 y^2-2 a b x y^3-b^2 y^4+x^2 y^2+y^4}-c x y}{y^2}\right\},\left\{d\to \frac{\sqrt{-a^2 x^2 y^2-2 a b x y^3-b^2 y^4+x^2 y^2+y^4}-c x y}{y^2}\right\},\left\{a\to -\sqrt{1-c^2},y\to 0\right\},\left\{a\to \sqrt{1-c^2},y\to 0\right\},\{x\to 0,y\to 0\}\right\}
$$

which is anything but. So why (1) and (2) give me different results?

Comment: What you are inputting to Mathematica is treating your vector as an unknown, which it is not supposed to be in the problem you are trying to solve (finding M such that.. etc)

Comment: Mathematica has `SolveAlways` for this.

Comment: @TrevorGunn I tried it with SolveAlways, and I end up getting all the correct orthogonal solutions. That's great, but I do not understand why SolveAlways gives solutions that are not given by Solve. Is it the case that the solutions of SolveAlways are 'hidden' within the complicated solutions I got with Solve?

Comment: Solve gives solutions for a,b,c,d in terms of x and y. SolveAlways gives solutions for a,b,c,d that work *always* (meaning for all x, y).

Comment: @TrevorGunn But surely the solutions of SolveAlways are a subset of those identified by Solve?

Comment: In principle, yes, but you might need to specialize. For example take ax + b = 0. Solve will give you something like a = -b/x and SolveAlways will give a = 0, b = 0.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I don't see that anyone has written out
$$ 
(a x+b y)^2+(c x+d y)^2=x^2+y^2 \tag{2b}
$$

$$ a^2 x^2 + 2abxy + b^2 y^2 + c^2 x^2 + 2cdxy + d^2 y^2 = x^2 + y^2 $$
for all $x,y,$ which means the coefficients agree. 
$$ (a^2 +c^2) x^2 + (2ab+2cd)xy + (b^2 + d^2) y^2 = x^2 + y^2 = 1 x^2 + 0 xy + 1 y^2 $$

$$ a^2 + c^2 = 1 \; , \; \; 2(ab+cd) = 0\; , \; \; b^2 + d^2 = 1 $$

So your
$$
\left(
\begin{array}{cc}
a & b \\
c & d \\
\end{array}
\right)
$$
has two unit vectors as columns, and these columns are orthogonal to each other. It is an orthogonal matrix.

Answer (score 3):

The 2 equations
$$M^TM=I$$
and
$$v^TM^TMv=v^Tv$$
are equivalent if you put $\forall v$ in front of the second equation. This actually gives you infinitely many equations which together pin down the matrix to exactly $M^TM=I$. Solving the second equation for a single unknown vector is just using one of those infinitely many equations, which leaves more freedom on the matrix $M^TM$.

---

To see why the two equations are equivalent, notice that
$$(\forall c: c^Ta = c^Tb) \implies a = b \label{a}\tag{1}$$
Indeed, 
$$
\begin{aligned}
(\forall c: c^Ta = c^Tb) &\iff (\forall c: c^Ta - c^Tb = 0)\\
&\iff (\forall c: c^T(a-b) = 0)\\
&\stackrel{*}\iff a-b = 0\\
&\iff a = b
\end{aligned}
$$
The equivalence indicated with $*$ says that 0 is the only vector that is orthogonal to all vectors. We notice that $a-b$ is orthogonal to all vectors so it must be $0$.

Also notice that
$$(\forall v: v^TM^TMv=v^Tv) \implies (\forall v,w: v^TM^TMw=v^Tw) \label{b}\tag{2}$$
by using the [polarisation identity](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Polarization_identity) twice:
$$
\begin{aligned}
v^TM^TMw &= \frac{1}{4}((v+w)^TM^TM(v+w) - (v-w)^TM^TM(v-w))\\
&= \frac{1}{4}((v+w)^T(v+w) - (v-w)^T(v-w))\\
&= v^Tw
\end{aligned}
$$

Applying \ref{a} with $a:=M^TMw$ and $b:=w$ and using \ref{b} we get
$$
\begin{aligned}
(\forall v: v^TM^TMv=v^Tv) &\implies (\forall v,w: v^TM^TMw=v^Tw)\\
&\implies (\forall w:M^TMw = w)\\
&\implies M^TM = I
\end{aligned}$$

The other direction is trivial.

Comment: So I cannot use =(,) to represent all such vectors (in this case, in 2-d)? Can you explain in more details the difference between any vectors and all vectors?

Comment: What steps fails if $\forall c$ or $\forall v$ is not present?

Comment: I will indicate this step in the prove with an edit, and explain why.

Comment: I felt a little uncomfortable of your derivation on the sentence "applying this with $a :=$...". Note that your $a, b$ and $c$  are independent in your earlier derivation while behind "Applying", $v$ and $M^TMv$ are not independent -- both of them depend on $v$.

Comment: You need this: https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Polarization_identity

Comment: Okay, so I think I understand; neglecting to add $\forall c$ adds new freedom and therefore additional valid solutions for , than just the orthogonal solutions. However, my Mathematica solutions are more restrictive, in the sense that they do not include the orthogonal solutions! Why am I losing freedom? If you remove the "degenerate" solutions $x=0$ and/or $y=0$ from the set of solutions I get, I only end up with two solutions and neither make $M$ orthogonal.

Comment: @Zhanxiong and TrevorGunn you are right. I will try to edit to get it right but it will become a bit more complicated

Comment: Actually, if I use SolveAlways, as suggested in an earlier comment, I get the orthogonal solutions.

Comment: The equivalence is not trivial --- I think it would be better if you can show us the details.

Comment: @Zhanxiong Done

Comment: @JensRenders Great, thank you.

Answer (score 1):

$x^2, xy, y^2$ are a basis for quadratic forms in $x$ and $y$, meaning

$$ax^2 + bxy + cy^2 = a'x^2 + b'xy + c'y^2 \text{ for all }x,y \in \mathbf{R}$$

if and only if $a = a', b = b', c = c'$.

If you set $x = 1, y = 0$, you get $a = a'$. If you set $x = 0, y = 1$ you get $c = c'$. Therefore we must also have $bxy = b'xy$ (for all $x, y$) from which it follows that $b = b'$.